# Using reflection in an enum

Tags: java, reflection

I have an enum that implements an interface:

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {

  ENUM1{         
     @Override
     public String myMethod(){               
      //blah
     }    
  },
  ENUM2{         
     @Override
     public String myMethod(){               
      //blah         
     }    
  }

}
```

If I know the enum value that I want to invoke a method on, given those 2 pieces of information: enum (ENUM2 for example), and the method name, how can I use reflection to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you think you would do it? What do you know about reflection that can help you?

Comment: Well I know its something like Method m = object.getClass().getMethod(methodName); Then I would call invoke on the method object.

Comment: Ok, so where are you having a hard time? The javadoc is helpful in this case.

Comment: If this was just a standard class, I think it would be easier. I'm just thrown off because I need to invoke the method on the enum. I updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: An `enum` constant acts the same way as any object. Now that you have a `Method`, you can call `invoke()`.

Comment: Why? If you already know that it's an ENUM1, what do you need reflection for? A. You don't.

Answer (score 0):

In brief (code that is not tested, just give you an idea):

```
Method m = MyEnum.class.getMethod("myMethod", String.class);
m.invoke(MyEnum.ENUM2, inputString);
```

Personally I would advise you to get a book, and learn the basics of reflection.  What you are trying to do is obviously not written by someone who has bare basic knowledge of reflection.